# 'S3' object has no attribute 'get_object_lock_configuration'

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I'm trying to implement the object lock feature but functions (get/put_object_lock_configuration) are not available :

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.17.64'
>>> client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> client.get_object_lock_configuration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'get_object_lock_configuration'

>>> client.get_object_lock_configuration(Bucket='tst', ExpectedBucketOwner='tst')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'get_object_lock_configuration'
```

**Edit:**
object lock functions not showing in python (tab tab) :

```
>>> client.get_object_
client.get_object_acl(      client.get_object_tagging(  client.get_object_torrent(

>>> client.put_object
client.put_object(          client.put_object_acl(      client.put_object_tagging(
```

Answer (score 1):

get_object_lock_configuration is a [function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_lock_configuration) not a property.

You need to call it like that:

```
response = client.get_object_lock_configuration(
    Bucket='string',
    ExpectedBucketOwner='string'
)
```

Comment: `>>> client.get_object_lock_configuration(Bucket='tst', ExpectedBucketOwner='tst')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'get_object_lock_configuration'
`

Answer (score 0):

The syntanx to call function client.**get_object_lock_configuration**:

```
response = client.get_object_lock_configuration(
    Bucket='string',
    ExpectedBucketOwner='string'
)
```

Syntax to call function client.**put_object_lock_configuration**:

```
response = client.put_object_lock_configuration(
    Bucket='string',
    ObjectLockConfiguration={
        'ObjectLockEnabled': 'Enabled',
        'Rule': {
            'DefaultRetention': {
                'Mode': 'GOVERNANCE'|'COMPLIANCE',
                'Days': 123,
                'Years': 123
            }
        }
    },
    RequestPayer='requester',
    Token='string',
    ContentMD5='string',
    ExpectedBucketOwner='string'
)
```

To know more please refer to this: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_lock_configuration

**Edit:**

Example Code:

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.get_object_lock_configuration(
Bucket='anynewname')

print(response)
```

Output sytanx:

```
{
    'ObjectLockConfiguration': {
        'ObjectLockEnabled': 'Enabled',
        'Rule': {
            'DefaultRetention': {
                'Mode': 'GOVERNANCE'|'COMPLIANCE',
                'Days': 123,
                'Years': 123
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: It will throw an error if object lock config is not set on bucket.**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ObjectLockConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetObjectLockConfiguration operation: Object Lock configuration does not exist for this bucket",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.get_object_lock_configuration(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 676, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `>>> client.get_object_lock_configuration(Bucket='tst', ExpectedBucketOwner='tst') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in __getattr__     self.__class__.__name__, item) AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'get_object_lock_configuration'`

Comment: @vinegaref I have edited the answer with example code.